# Getting 'No such object' error when trying to download gcloud app engine builds

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, gcloud

I have a Django application running on google app engine. Just because I don't know how to use Git, I usually download latest app engine version from google cloud build and work with different folder names. However this last week, when I try to download my google app engine project, I get this following error:

***No such object: staging.project-id.appspot.com/eu.gcr.io/project-id/appengine/default.datetime:latest***

I know I can get my files from cloud shell but I couldn't do it. Thats how I have found cloud builds after searching it for like a week.

Note: My Django app is still running.

Answer (score 1):

A Cloud Storage bucket named `staging.project-id.appspot.com` was deleted or missing.

The Cloud Build files are stored in a Cloud Storage to serve as staging before being deployed to App Engine. You can try redeployment to re-create the said bucket.

Here's another option to download your App Engine code: [Downloading Your Source Code](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code)